# How to merge all partitions from dynamic disk

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

I've been resizing and creating partitions on my disk a few days ago, and I accidentally converted it to dynamic disk because of Disk Management prompt, till here no problem

But now I found myself with many partitions that have the same name

I want to merge all this partitions without losing data and withouting converting it to Basic Disk, because there are too many partitions for a Basic Disk I think

Disk Management screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlbgZ.jpg

Explorer screenshot (dynamic disk partitions are marked in red): https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuJVA.png

Comment: You don't have partitions of the same name, you have multiple partitions that together represent one drive. (spanned volume) read for details of dynamic discs https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/basic-and-dynamic-disks#dynamic-disks

Comment: Backup everything and repartition. And never do this again.